# WCF with two endpoints accessed from java

Tags: java, eclipse, wcf

I have a WCF that has two endpoints, one for https one for http.

In java I access this service by typing in something like this:

http://service.svc?wsdl

How will this work now that there are two endpoints?  Does simply changing it from http to https in the address change the endpoint?  Or is there something more I need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Endpoint defines address exposed for remote calls. If you have two endpoints (one for HTTP and one for HTTPS) with default address defined (empty) your service will be exposed on:

- http://service.svc
- https://service.svc

But it doesn't mean that metadata will be exposed on both http and https as well. Metadata are exposed on [separate Mex endpoints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734765.aspx) which again must be either for HTTP or HTTPS. Accessing Metadata through browser requires enabling `serviceMetadata` behaviour which provides separate properties `httpGetEnabled` and `httpsGetEnabled` to allow accessing ?wsdl address from HTTP and HTTPS.